# Different PHPSESSID in WebSocket handshake

Tags: php, cookies, websocket

When the WebSocket handshake is done I receive a PHPSESSID different from the one in the browser, why is this?

[image]

Client code for connecting:

```
websocket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.0.109:9000/php_servers/socketserver1/socketserver.php");
```

Server code for reading header:

```
<?php
include "../serverfunctions.php";
include "eventfunctions.php";

$host = '192.168.0.109';
$port = '9000';
$null = NULL;

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);
socket_listen($socket);
$clients = array($socket);

while (true) 
{
    $changed = $clients;
    socket_select($changed, $null, $null, 0, 10);

    if (in_array($socket, $changed)) 
    {
        $socket_new = socket_accept($socket); 
        $clients[] = $socket_new; 
        $header = socket_read($socket_new, 1024);
```